# Basic proxy_pass from nginx from one local ip to another local ip

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am a new user of nginx and I am following a video guide from Linode on youtube (How to Set Up an NGINX Reverse Proxy).

I have a working nginx and apache server both on port 80. I know that because when I type the ip address of both in firefox, it directs me to nginx/apache welcome page.

The youtube video configuration template is as follow (where the server_name is the linode ip) :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [..]:80;

  server_name 172.105.104.226;
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
```

On my Proxmox machine, the nginx server is on a VM at 192.168.1.241 and the apache server on another VM at 192.168.1.243.

Looking at nginx documentation we find that this :

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/link/;
}
```

should proxy all the traffic received on the nginx listening port and redirect it to the address specified by proxy pass.

With all these information, my configuration file is like this :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name 192.168.1.241;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.243;
    }
}
```

My understanding is that this configuration file should listen at the address 192.168.1.241 on port 80 (nginx server) and redirect it to the specified address 192.168.1.243 (apache server)/

If i understand correctly, `Location /` should take the request as is received on the nginx server and redirect it to the apache server.

However, when I enter 192.168.1.241 in my browser, it doesn't show the apache welcome message but shows the nginx welcome message. That means that the proxy isn't working.

My nginx understanding is extremely limited as I am just starting to learn, but to me it seems like this should work but doesn't.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the configuration is correct.

The problem was that the webpage was cached. By forcing a full refresh, 192.168.1.241 redirected to 192.168.1.243 successfully.